# How to remove a tracked directory from local but keep in the repository?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have a directory named *downloader* in my Magento application's root directory.

At present it in version control. I want to make it possible that the directory and files should be version control (In the repository) to track any changes.

But I want to remove it safely from the production server and when ever I do ***git pull*** the directory should not be pulled on the server.

Also the there should be not message like  **deleted:    downloader/** after deletion of directory from production server.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

There is a feature called sparse checkout that allows you to do this - it basically tells Git to locally ignore part of your repository when checking out or when interacting with the index, e.g. `git status`.

Documentation here: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-read-tree#_sparse_checkout

Brief summary of what to do:

- On your production server, at the top level of the repo, create a file `.git/info/sparse-checkout` and add two patterns, each on its own line: `*` and `!/downloader/` (together meaning: everything but the `downloader` dir on the top level)
- Enable this whole thing: `git config core.sparseCheckout true`
- Run `git reset` - this will unstage any staged changes and, as a side effect, apply the patterns to your index so `git status`, `git add` and friends know about them.